# Play pure sound (one frequency) and recognize frequencies C++

Tags: c++, macos, audio

I would like to know:
 - Is there a C++ library for `OS X` that will allow me to play a pure sound
 - Again for `OS X` is there a library that would allow me to find the frequencies of sounds coming from a live microphone (not a recording)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Those are dramatically different requirements. Playing a tone of a given frequency is a pretty ordinary thing, and I expect the standard OSX runtime to have some sort of functionality in itself. Detecting the frequency of incoming audio requires a fair bit of math, doing a Fourier Transformation on the sampled audio. I did this for sampled audio using the numpy package for Python (in my case, I didn't need to do it realtime, but I'm sure that's possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tone generation you might have luck with [STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/compile.html), and I wouldn't be surprised if it has sample code to do what you are asking. (See [sinewave](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/classstk_1_1SineWave.html))

Finding the frequencies of an input signal is a complicated question, and has a variety of solutions depending on what you need. Cinder++ has an [FFT](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.6/classcinder_1_1audio_1_1dsp_1_1_fft.html) class, and much more.

If you were willing to use something other than C++ there are audio specific languages and tools that can help you do these things. You could embed [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net), for example.

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for in Cinder++. But I'll have to make everything work. Thank you very much.